# GROUP BY clause SQL invalid aggregate function

Tags: sql

I'm trying to group by 'Condicion' but it takes an error:

> Column 'exercisepractice.Cantidad' is invalid in the select list
> because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
> GROUP BY clause.

What am I doing wrong here? I am getting this error on:

```
create view exercisepractice
as
select 'Aprobados' as Condicion, sum(case when Promedio>13.5  then 1 else 0 end) as 'Cantidad', A.Sexo
from vAlumnos A inner join vMatricula M
on(A.CodAlumno=M.CodAlumno)
inner join vNotas N
on (M.NroMatricula=N.NroMatricula)
where N.SemAcademico='2020-I'
GROUP BY A.Sexo
union all
select 'Aprobados' as Condicion, sum(case when Promedio>13.5  then 1 else 0 end) as 'Cantidad', A.Sexo
from vAlumnos A inner join vMatricula M
on(A.CodAlumno=M.CodAlumno)
inner join vNotas N
on (M.NroMatricula=N.NroMatricula)
where N.SemAcademico='2020-I'
GROUP by A.Sexo
union all
select 'Desprobados' as Condicion, sum(case when Promedio<13.5  then 1 else 0 end) as 'Cantidad', A.Sexo
from vAlumnos A inner join vMatricula M
on(A.CodAlumno=M.CodAlumno)
inner join vNotas N
on (M.NroMatricula=N.NroMatricula)
where N.SemAcademico='2020-I'
GROUP BY A.Sexo
union all
select 'Desaprobados' as Condicion, sum(case when Promedio<13.5  then 1 else 0 end) as 'Cantidad', A.Sexo
from vAlumnos A inner join vMatricula M
on(A.CodAlumno=M.CodAlumno)
inner join vNotas N
on (M.NroMatricula=N.NroMatricula)
where N.SemAcademico='2020-I'
GROUP by A.Sexo 

select * from exercisepractice
GROUP by Condicion
```

[image]

My expected result is like this:

| CONDICION | CANTIDAD | SEXO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aprobados | XXXX | M |
| Aprobados | XXXX | F |
| Desaprobados | XXXX | M |
| Desaprobados | XXXX | F |

Answer (score 0):

LOL I was duplicating 'Approved' and 'Disapproved'